# Regarding Android releases

Tags: android, release

I have a question which bothered me for a long time. We all know Android is an open sourced project. But why so many people even developers are looking forward a new release? If it is open sourced, before Google releases Android 2.3, we cannot find any 2.3 code from repository? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different degrees of open source.  While Google open sources each Android release, they don't do it until after each version releases.

Thus, the development of the core Android platform is not actually open while it's happening.

However, the Android Development Tools are developed in open source and it's possible to participate in those as it actually occurs.

Lots more info at http://source.android.com/faqs.html

Comment: That's because it has been released. It's only been available for a week or so.

Answer (score -3):

hey echo... android is a hot property in tech town today.. people say that it will give apple a run for its money... So, there is no big surprise when people wait for itz release.. More over, from a developer point of view,  the present 2.2 version very difficult and fro user point of view, they are waiting for some new features to be added.... It might be an open source but brand GOOGLE has made it such a hot property

Comment: What are you talking about? This answer is very incoherent and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, capitalization, spelling, and grammar.